# Rails: adding new has_and_belongs_to_many associations without creating objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

Is it possible to simply add new associations?

I have two objects tied together via has_and_belongs_to_many. **Model A** will always be unique but corresponding **Model B** objects might already be in the database.

When **Model A** is created how do I tell Rails to find corresponding **Model B** objects and tie the two models together - or - if no the appropriate **Model B** object does not exist then go ahead and create it?
Should I do a .where lookup and then a SQL query to add the two IDs to the join table, or is there a native ActiveRecord method for doing this?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a many-many relationship, if it is, you need to create a join table which contains model_a_id and model_b_id and not simply a foreign key in model_b.

Comment: @Gazier thanks for pointing that out, I rewrote the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
# the piece from create action of ProductsController
categories = Array.new(@product.categories)
@product.categories.clear
categories.each do |c|
  @product.categories << Category.find_or_create_by_name(c.name)
end
# ready to @product.save
```

Answer (score 1):

A Rails association does not tie models in a restricted manner. Suppose that you have a User and a Post model. The association User has_many Posts simply creates an interface. Using that interface, you can now do :

```
user.posts
```

and this will return all the posts of the user. If you want to add or find a post, you can execute :

```
Post.find_or_create_by_user_id(...)
```

This will either find the post or create it.

Also, in your example, you mention a one to many association. Thus you do not need a has and belongs to many association, but a has_many/belongs_to one.